# Non-admin account should not have shutdown & restart privileges

Tags: windows-8.1, access-control, security-policy

The admin account on my PC should **ALWAYS BE RUNNING**.

I am allowing other accounts to use the PC (includes running apps of course) while the admin is logged in but i want to prevent that non-admin from shutting down or restarting the pc. How to do that in windows 8.1?

Also, is there a way to sandbox that non-admin? I mean to protect the whole PC resources from crashing or running suspicious scripts/files. No to virtual software, it will eat a lot of resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent users from shutting down the system by changing the local security policy.

- From Start type `Local Security Policy` and it should pop as you type
- Expand `Local Policies`
- Select `User Rights Assignment`
- in the right pane, double click `Shut down the system`
- Select `Users` and click `Remove`
- Click `Apply`

Comment: thanks. do you have any suggestion about the sandbox thing?

Comment: that is much more difficult and should be a different question

Answer (score 1):

Run Secpol.msc pressing the Win + R button

Go to Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Shut down the system.

and remove users you don't want there.